# Access data in Dictionary from NSCountedSet objects

Tags: swift, dictionary, nscountedset

I have an `NSCountedSet` consisting of `String` objects, if I iterate over the set and print it out, I see something like this:

```
for item in countedSet {
    print(item)
}

Optional(One)
Optional(Two)
```

The countedSet is created from an `Array` of `String` objects:

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: countedArray)
```

If I print the array I see something like this:

```
["Optional(One)", "Optional(One)", "Optional(One)", "Optional(Two)", "Optional(Two)"]
```

Now, I want to use those counted strings to access data in a `Dictionary`, where the keys are `String` type and the values have the type `[String : AnyObject]`. If I print the dictionary, I see all the data.

However, if I use of the objects from the countedSet to access the dictionary, I always get a nil value back:

```
for item in countedSet {
    let key = item as? String
    let data = dictionary[key!]  // Xcode forced me to unwrap key

    print(data)
}

nil
nil
```

But

```
let key = "One"
let data = dictionary[key]
```

gives me the expected data.

What am I missing here, how can I access my data from the countedSet objects?

**UPDATE**: solved thanks to the comment from Martin R.  The `String` objects were originally `NSString` objects (obtained from `NSScanner`), and I was casting them wrongly:

```
let string = String(originalString)
```

after I changed it to:

```
let string = (originalString as! String)
```

All works fine.

Comment: I assume that the problem is how you add the strings to the counted set.

Comment: See my updated question